# How to check why my custom validator isn't working?

Tags: angular, forms, validation

so I'm trying to create an angular reactive form that has an ID input field which must be unique (in the sense that if the submitted ID already exists, an error should pop up on the angular html front).
The logic behind it is to check the submitted input against the database (using HTTPclient requests).
Also using debouncetime operator in order to try and minimize the amount of requests the server gets.

Problem is, the REST server isn't getting any get requests at all.

The TS code looks like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import {matchOtherValidator} from '../match-other-validator';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import {map,debounceTime} from 'rxjs/operators';

const tzAsyncValidator = (http: HttpClient) => (c: FormControl)=>{
  console.log(c.value);
  if (!c|| String (c.value).length ===0){
    return of(null);
  }
  return http.get('http://localhost:4000/userIds/'+ String (c.value))
  .pipe(
    debounceTime(500),
    map((ids:any[])=>{
      console.log(ids);
      return ids.length ===1
      ? true : {exists:null};
    }),
  );
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.component.css']
})

export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit { 
  public newUser;
  public verification;
  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }



  ngOnInit() {
    this.newUser = new FormGroup({
      Tz: new FormControl ('',[Validators.required,Validators.minLength(4),Validators.maxLength(9),tzAsyncValidator(this.http)]),
      Email: new FormControl ('',[Validators.required,Validators.email]),
      PW: new FormControl ('', [Validators.required,Validators.pattern('^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$')]),
      PWVerification: new FormControl ('', [Validators.required,Validators.pattern('^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$'),matchOtherValidator('PW')])
    })

  }
  onSubmit() {

  }
}
```

Any input would be appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The async validators should go in the third parameter of the FormControl constructor. See below.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.newUser = new FormGroup({
        Tz: new FormControl('', // value or state
            [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4),
                Validators.maxLength(9)],  // sync validators 2nd parameter
            [tzAsyncValidator(this.http)]), // async validators 3rd parameter
        ...
  })
}
```

For more information see [this](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl).

Comment: That did it! It seems I only need to move the async validator to be the 3rd parameter! Thank you